# Select specific target jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make a specific target for tag element, since I want to add some class for the specific `i` tag with class `icon`, while the parent `li` target is collapsed the `ul`:

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // add class to the 'i' tag element
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <a>      
   <li> 
      <span>Menu</span>
      <span><i class="icon"></i></span>
      <ul>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>
      </ul>
   </li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>Other Menu</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>Other Menu</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>Other Menu</li>
  </a>
  <a>
   <li>
      <span>Menu</span>
      <span><i class="icon"></i></span>
      <ul>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>    
      </ul>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only the `<li>` element can be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: @j08691 But, you can have an `<li>` with an `<a>` inside it, producing the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this without changing any of your existing code.

```
 $('ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // add class to the 'i' tag element
    $(this).prev().find("span>i.icon").addClass("someclass");
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, if they "try this", they do change their code, don't they? ;) And then they still have some invalid markup...

Comment: Haha yeah @Connum i agree. How would they end up having invalid markup ?

Comment: Because their markup already is invalid, with a tags as direct child nodes of ul and some invalid closing tags. But seeing they marked the answer as accepted anyway, they obviously made their choice that they don't care... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can store the clicked `<li>` element in a local variable, e.g. `$this`. Then from inside the `slideToggle()` callback, you can just re-use it and `find()` your `<i>` inside.

Also, your closing `<a>` tags were wrong, it has to be `</a>`, not `<a/>`. And a `<ul>` can only have `<li>` elements as direct child nodes. If what you were trieng to achieve by that was merely to have a hand cursor, you can just set `cursor: pointer` vias CSS, or have the links directly inside the `<li>`s.

Working example with a demo class to show it having any effect:

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
     $this.find('i').addClass('aclass');
  });
})
```

```css
/* test style: */
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li i.aclass {
  border: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
   <li> 
      <span>Menu</span>
      <span><i class="icon"></i></span>
      <ul>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Other Menu</li>
   <li>Other Menu</li>
   <li>Other Menu</li>
   <li>
      <span>Menu</span>
      <span><i class="icon"></i></span>
      <ul>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>
        <a><li>Sub menu1</li></a>    
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using a `.toggleClass('aclass')` makes more sense here. Don't you think?

Comment: Yes, probably. Thought about that as well, but the question strictly stated "add class". Could be the case that OP want to mark any menu items that have been toggled once.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the link that you click and use it later, I think, adding `preventDefault` is a good way to prevent scrolling page.

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  const $link = $(e.target);

  $link.children('ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
     $link.find('i').addClass('aclass');
  });
})
```